# jQuery Drop-down navigation menu library to open all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, superfish

I am trying to implement a similar menu behavior as on Harvard's website: http://www.seas.harvard.edu/computer-science
where all the sections drop down no matter which link you put the mouse over.

Does anybody know what they are using for that? The closest I could find is the jQuery Superfish menu, but it only allows to open one menu section at a time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Likely it's the way it's designed.  They probably have one dropdown div, which contains other divs (what you traditional separated dropdowns would be). After dropping the main dropdown, they highlight the background of one of the contained divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fLCL/1/) which portrays what I was talking about in my comment.  The particular result you are looking for is a simple modification of a normal drop down menu.  Instead of having each of the drop downs be their own separate divs, you put them in a container div and display it when a drop down is needed.

So instead of:

```
<div id="drpDwn1"></div>
<div id="drpDwn2"></div>
<div id="drpDwn3"></div>
```

You'd have:

```
<div id="drpDwnFull">
    <div id="drpDwn1"></div>
    <div id="drpDwn2"></div>
    <div id="drpDwn3"></div>
</div>
```

You would change the visibility on `drpDwnFull` instead of the individual items to get the full menu effect.

Then you can add highlighting as you wish.  In my Demo I chose to highlight the menu associated with the menu item, as well as the individual item you are hovering over.